# Multi dimensional array in JQ

Tags: json, updates, edit, jq

Can some one please help to transform the input json to output format like i specified below . i tried multiple ways but i could not succeed.

I have input :

```
 {
        "hosts": [
            {
                "statistics": [
                    {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "date": "2017-06-09",
                            "time": "21:40:01"
                        },
                        "cpu-load": [
                            {
                                "idle": 99.64
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need output :

```
{

    "hosts": [
        {
            "statistics": [
                {
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-09 21:40:01",
                    "cpu-load": [
                        {
                            "idle": 99.64
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please share what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update operator |= should do the trick.

```
jq '.hosts[].statistics[].timestamp |= .date + " " + .time'
```